# How to estimate alpha and beta for beta-distribution in to run pglm regression

Tags: r, regression, panel, beta, fixed-width

I am trying to run a fixed-effects regression model on panel data in R. My dependent variable (the share of workers on long-term contracts) is bounded from 0 to 1, and I use the pglm package. The settings are: effect = "individual", model = "within", family = beta. I get an error: argument "a" is missing, with no default. Apparently, I need to specify the alpha and beta for beta distribution. How could I get them?

Comment: Hard to say without any code... Anyway there's no beta family available in this package. Try the **betareg** package.

Comment: model  <- pglm(servS1 ~ pastS + horS + wheat + lpd + tri + henley + city + wjob1A + turn + rail + agroS + paupSRSD + enc10, data = pdata, 
                                 effect = "individual", model = "within", family = beta(10, 20))

Comment: 10 and 20 are just random numbers. But I get an error message: Error in family$link : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors. I wonder what could be wrong?

Comment: I repeat: ***there's no beta family available in this package***.